# Ссылка на неразрешённый внешний символ

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Engine", nullptr, nullptr);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(1 , 0 , 0 , 1);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);


    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления    Подробности
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_glClearColor в функции main.   Engine  C:\OpenGL\Engine\Window.obj 1